# Density of Hermite functions

Tags: functional-analysis

Denote by $H$ the linear span of Hermite functions, i.e., $H=\{P(x)e^{-x^2/2},\,\text{$P$ is polynomial on $\mathbb R$}\}$. It is well known that $H$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ and consequently in $L^p(\mathbb R)$ for $p\in [1,2]$.

**Indeed:** denote $w(x)=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$. By Hölder inequality,
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\|hw\|_p
\le \|h^pw^\frac{p}{2}\|_{\frac2p}^\frac1p \|w^\frac{p}{2}\|_{\frac{2}{2-p}}^\frac1p
\le \|hw^\frac{1}{2}\|_{2} \|w\|_{\frac{p}{2-p}}^\frac12
\le C_p \left(\int_{\mathbb R} h^2(x)w(x)\mathrm dx\right)^\frac12
\end{equation}

for $p\in[1,2)$.
Next, let $\varepsilon>0$ be given anl let $f\in C_0$. Take $g=f/w$. Then $g\in C_0$ and by the $L^2$-density, there is a polynomial $P$ such that
$$
\left(\int_{\mathbb R} (g(x)-P(x))^2w(x)\mathrm dx\right)^\frac12<\varepsilon.
$$
Then, by (1), $\|f-Pw\|_p<C_p\varepsilon$. The rest follows by the density of $C_0$ in $L^p$.

**Question:** Is it true that $H$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbb R)$? What about $(L^1\cap L^\infty)(\mathbb R)$? (The norm is given as $\max\{\|\cdot\|_1,\|\cdot\|_\infty\}$).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a reference for the $L^1 case? Someone was looking for such a reference in this forum some time ago.

Comment: Edit: I sketched the proof above. The $L^2$ density is proved at wikipedia, for instance.

Comment: Do you have a reference for or a proof for the $L^1$ case? Others here were unable to find such a theorem or proof for the $L^1$ case.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a reference; I proved it by myself...

Answer (score 0):

Yes both times, follows directly from the density in $L^1$, since both $C_0$ and $L^1\cap L^{\infty}$ are subspaces of it.

Comment: This is true if we take the inherited $L^1$ norm on those subspaces. However, the norm on $L^1\cap L^\infty$ is much larger and the space $C_0$ is not even embedded into $L^1$.